# Python - Issue with creating a Thread subclass within a Process subclass - threading & multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm having trouble with trying to get a Thread (threading.Thread) subclass to work within a Process (multiprocessing.Process) subclass.

Here is the simplest working example to demonstrate the issue.
I make one "SubProcess" (instance of multiprocessing.Process), which will contain a child "WorkerThread" (instance of threading.Thread). Execution terminates at `subProcess.start()`

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading

class SubProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, daemon=True)

        #Instantiate this one worker
        self.workerThread = WorkerThread()

    def run(self):
        #Start the worker
        self.workerThread.start()

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)

    def run(self):
        #Real work code goes here
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Program starts here
    
    #Instantiate the SubProcess class - works fine
    subProcess = SubProcess()

    #Start the subProcess - Execution stops here - see Traceback below
    subProcess.start()

    subProcess.join()
```

Here is the output traceback:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[***]\simplestExampleError.py", line 31, in <module>
    subProcess.start()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

[***]>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I have reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026727/python-using-threads-within-multiprocessing) similar question, but the key difference is that they are defining the "WorkerThread" to point to a function, with predefined arguments (not a subclass of 'threading.Thread').
Example: Within the subProcess, they define `workerThread = Thread(target=print_all_the_things, args=("a", self.num))`

I require the ability to change the WorkerThread's class variables while it is running.
Example: In the subProcess, I would do something like `self.workerThread.input = "INPUT"` while both are running

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Process objects need to be pickleable and since your process has a non-pickleable instance attribute (self.workerThread) it also become non-pickleable. It might work if you move workerThread to a local variable within the scope of SubProcess.run

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see. Unfortunately adding the "workerThread" class definition & implementation into the SubProcess class did not prevent the error. Though, I do understand the issue now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+TypeError%3A+cannot+pickle+%27_thread.lock%27+object. BTW: It's questionable practice to derive from Thread and Process, it's like deriving from File just to read or write a file. Also, what do you expect to happen to the thread when starting the process? You may be trying to implement a flawed approach here, also known as "XY problem".

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply!
I did not know that it was questionable practice to derive from these classes. 
I have always thought of it as a convenient way to wrap a utility class (like Thread) with user defined data structures, which can be easily manipulated while the Thread was running.
I agree that I may be trying to implement a flawed approach, but this type of organization seems logical to me:
Spawn a Process -> Process spawns a Thread -> Thread conducts the work
If the Process wants to change what the Thread is working on, it can change one of the Thread's instance variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason with the code you posted (of course, you only posted very minimal code) why the instantiation of the worker thread needs to be done in the `SubProcess.__init__` method. I would simply do the initialization of the `workerThread` attribute in the `run` method:

```py
class SubProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, daemon=True)

    def run(self):
        #Instantiate this one worker
        self.workerThread = WorkerThread()
        #Start the worker
        self.workerThread.start()
```

I don't think it is a fatal flaw to derive classes from `Process` and `Thread` classes but it is not very flexible. What if the code using your `SubProcess` class wanted to assign a *name* attribute to the process? In your current implementation it can't without your redesigning the `__init__` method. The following implementation is just cleaner and makes the classes reusable in non-multiprocessing, non-multithreading scenarios (for which I would possibly choose different method names other than `run` that better describe the processing done by the method):

```py
import multiprocessing
import threading

class SubProcess:
    def __init__(self):
        # set whatever attributes are required (that can be pickled)
        ...

    def run(self): # or a more descriptive method name
        #Instantiate this one worker
        worker = Worker()
        self.workerThread = threading.Thread(target=worker.run, daemon=True)
        #Start the worker
        self.workerThread.start()

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        # set whatever attributes are required
        ...

    def run(self): # or a more descriptive method name
        #Real work code goes here
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess = SubProcess()
    # In this context, the Process does not need to be a daemon process
    # since we are waiting for its complettion:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=subprocess.run, name='SubProcess')
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Ah, Brilliant!
I hadn't considered the idea of moving the instantiation of the worker into the process run() function.

I was initially worried that manipulations of Worker instance variables (ex. Worker.input = "New Input") would not be received while the Worker Thread was running. But after running some tests, it works flawlessly.

You've helped me get past a stumbling block. Thank you so much!

Comment: hi, running this code on a windows or mac computer gives me `PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.SubProcess'>:` ,

Comment: You must have created attributes in `SubProcess.__init__` that cannot be pickled. Note my comment in the code: **# set whatever attributes are required (that can be pickled)**. The above code run under Windows, so you must have made changes. What were they?

Comment: Hi @Booboo , I must have my notifications for comments disabled, I'm very interested in your help. I was having some issues with the main script on pycharm, thanks for your reply